# Qt Designer Error on startup: the code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP140_1.dll was not found

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to learn PyQt but every time I run the Qt Designer, it fails with System Error- 'the code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP140_1dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem'. What should I do to fix this error? I use python 3.8.3 and I have installed visual studio 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening QtDesigner has nothing to do with your python version nor your IDE. This is most likely a corrupt installation or OS problem.

Try re-installing QtDesigner from this link: https://build-system.fman.io/static/public/files/Qt%20Designer%20Setup.exe

If it still doesn't work, it is most likely a C++ compiler error due to the `.dll` missing. Here's a video on how to repair that error: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XJ8_kUjVlk